# Drawer layout listView transparent background

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to set the background of the listview inside the drawer layout to be transparent like google's camera app.

What happens is whenever I set the background of the listview to be transparent its items disappears

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer_layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigation_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried to set it to a transparent image it didn't work either it doesn't work with any transparency added to the color of it's background.

This works:

```
        android:background="#232321"
```

This doesn't

```
        android:background="#fb232321"
```

Any idea how can I fix this problem

Comment: hi,please add here listview row xml file

Comment: Have you tried setting background of list items?

Comment: The list items have nothing to do with this problem, whenever I set the background of the listview to anything rather than an opaque color it disappears independent of its items or its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the I solved my problem by wrapping the listview with a Relativelayout it works with other layouts as well.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigation_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:background="@color/transparent"` on DrawerLayout view and not on the listView. Also, you can use background transparent on childView of your ListView

Comment: The list items have nothing to do with this problem, whenever I set the background of the listview to anything rather than an opaque color it disappears independent of its items or its parent.

Comment: Have you tried removing the background completely from the listView attributes?

Answer (score 0):

use #00000000 for black transparency

Comment: It doesn't work that way I've added the solution to my problem